# Is there a version of the central limit theorem which lets me replace Var(X) with the sample variance?

Tags: variance, central-limit-theorem, mathematical-statistics

So, usually with the central limit theorem we have something like this:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \mu_i)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2_i}} \to N(0,1) $$

My question is, is there a version of this in which, instead of $\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2_i$, I can use e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_i)^2$? Or something? I didn't quite bother to work out where all the factors of $n$ go, but essentially I want to know if I can use the sample variance to estimate the $\sigma_i$ (let's suppose that actually all the $X$ are i.i.d.), without screwing something up in the CLT. In the limit $n\to\infty$ the sample variance recovers the variance, so it seems like it should work, but I have not seen this version of the CLT written down.